# Understanding PHP Script Return

Tags: php

I would like to understand how "return" works in a php script. (not a function/method) but a standalone file.

*script.php*

```
 <?php
   return array("hello", "world");
```

How do I use *script.php* to fetch the array it is returning.

ps. noticed this usage in [sami (php api generator)](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/63/sami-yet-another-php-api-documentation-generator)